# Как передать заказчику телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

При выполнении заказов на ботов (python, aiogram), возникает вопрос — как передавать тг бота заказчику, если он на vds сервере. Или надо в самом начале регистрировать оплату на заказчика? Но не просить же у него банковскую карточку.

Comment: Просить бюджет на сервер? Он может и сам оплатить vds. Показать бота на локальной машине, а потом пусть оплатит вдс

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он 1. не о программировании, 2. объективный ответ невозможен.

Comment: В большинстве хостингов создается заказ, по которому можно сформировать ссылку для оплаты. Ему ее передаете, чтобы не брать у него данные карточки. Также показывать можно с локальной машины, как вам и сказали выше.

Comment: А вопрос нужно будет закрыть, т.к. не по теме.